# Session Timeout Notification on ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get notified like "Your session will expire in 1 mins".
I'm using ASP.NET core + React apps.

I've checked ASP.NET core documentation and stackoverflow, but no answer for ASP.NET core, just for ASP.NET.
Please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have any code to provide.

Comment: I don't know what to code.
I've searched everywhere but can't find any event that session is expiring in ASP.NET core.
And I want to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no event of session expiring.
You have to implement it manually.

```
function setupSessionTimeout(sessionExpirationTime) {
    var timeoutDuration = sessionExpirationTime * 60 * 1000;
    var timeoutId;

    function resetTimeout() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(notify, timeoutDuration); // Set timeout to trigger checkSessionExpired() after timeout duration
    }

    // Reset timeout on user activity (mousemove or keydown event)
    $(document).on('mousemove keydown', resetTimeout);

    // Initial setup
    resetTimeout(); // Set initial timeout
}

function notify() {
   alert("Session expired");
}
```